# Can not find module 'whatwg-fetch'.

Tags: node.js, npm, fetch, npm-install

I keep getting this error in my terminal: Cannot find module 'whatwg-fetch'

Since I was having difficulty putting together my own React skeleton, I decided to use one I found on youtube. Github repo: https://github.com/joellongie/superCell/blob/master/gulpfile.js

I'm thinking there is a conflict between what's in the gulp file and fetch but i'm not sure. I installed fetch via the terminal and I can see it in my package.json. I even see the fetch folder in the node_modules folder.

I already tried removing the node_modules folder and doing npm install again but I get the same error.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point out the problem.